# Passing data to DataGridViews

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, textbox

I have text boxes on my second form and a send button which is in the code shown below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    f1.PassName = richTextBox1.Text;
    f1.PassLastName = richTextBox2.Text;
    f1.PassAge = comboBox1.Text;
    f1.PassGender = richTextBox3.Text;
    f1.ShowDialog();
}
```

and a `DataGridView` on form 1 with this code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string name;
    private string lastName;
    private string age;
    private string gender;

    public string PassName
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string PassLastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }

    public string PassAge
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }

    public string PassGender
    {
        get { return gender; }
        set { gender = value; }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = name;
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = lastName;
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = age;
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = gender;
    }

    private void mnuExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //adding the quit on the top file with caution message
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Quit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    private void addTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(); //show form2 so user can input data
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}`
```

This is fine if I want to send one set of data to the `DataGridView`, but if I add new information again then this opens a new `DataGridView` and stores it to another seperate `DataGridView` then I have two `DataGridView` forms. I want to put all the data onto one `DataGridView` and keep adding rows. So when the user clicks the add button on the first form with the `DataGridView`, it opens up the `TextBox` form which is form 2, then the user fills out the information and clicks the send button which sends the information back to the `DataGridView`, however this then opens up a new window with a new `DataGridView`. I dont want this to happen I want it to keep adding rows on the first form.
Could someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ShowDialog(this)** and **Owner** to get the parent form's property.

**Form1**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Move to Form1_Activated
    this.Activated += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Activated); //connect
}

private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = name;
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = lastName;
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = age;
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = gender;
}

private void addTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(); //show form2 so user can input data
    f2.ShowDialog(this);//set this form as Owner
}
```

**Form2**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = (Form1)this.Owner;//Get the Owner form
    f1.PassName = richTextBox1.Text;
    f1.PassLastName = richTextBox2.Text;
    f1.PassAge = comboBox1.Text;
    f1.PassGender = richTextBox3.Text;
    //f1.ShowDialog();
    f1.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, however now when i click on the send button none of the textbox/combobox fields are displayed in the datagridview. Any ideas?

Comment: Which button is send button? button1 in Form2?

Comment: Did you connect Form1_Activated with your Form1?

Comment: The send button is button1 in form 2 yep and what do you mean when you say connect?

Comment: Good,glad to help you.